# javascript Set with objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When merging array of strings, I can use `Set` and ES6 to remove duplicates like so:

```
const a = ["hello", "hi", "yo"]
const b = ["alo", "hi"]
const remove_hi = [
  ...new Set([
    ...a,
    ...b,
  ]),
]
```

But how do I compare and remove objects?
Say I have this:

```
const a = [
  {id: "asd", name: "Hi"},
  {id: "fgh", name: "Hello"},
  {id: "123", name: "Hi"}
]
const b = [
  {id: "jkl", name: "Yo"},
  {id: "123", name: "Hi"}
]
// This will not work. It will have a duplicate of {id: "123", name: "Hi"}
const remove_hi = [
  ...new Set([
    ...a,
    ...b,
  ]),
]
```

How do I remove `{id: "123", name: "Hi"}` from a combined array with `Set`?

Comment: I'd stringify the objects first, and store that in the Set

Comment: Possibly if the position of the objects keys would not change, but there must be a better more elegant way

Comment: Other ways will require iterating through each item in the Set and checking each object's properties and values. Possible, but extremely cumbersome. If I were in this situation, I'd take a step back and consider if there was a different way to approach the problem other than putting objects into a Set

Comment: Do you want to deduplicate by `id`, or by the combination of `id` and `name`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts actually by `name`

Comment: Sounds like you want a `Map` keyed by `name` instead of a `Set`.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter. The solution would apply whether by `name`, or by `id`. And @loganfsmyth, sure, I'm ok with `Map`... trying to think how to do it...

Comment: Since you want to deduplicate by `name`, do you want to keep the fist occurrence or the last occurrence (say the first object had a different id than the second one with the same name, which one should be kept)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to deduplicate by the key `name`:

```js
const uniqueBy = (array, key) => [
  ...new Map(
    array.map(o => [key(o), o])
  ).values()
];

const a = [
  {id: "asd", name: "Hi"},
  {id: "fgh", name: "Hello"},
  {id: "123", name: "Hi"}
]
const b = [
  {id: "jkl", name: "Yo"},
  {id: "123", name: "Hi"}
]
const remove_hi = uniqueBy([...a, ...b], o => o.name);

console.log(remove_hi);
```

Note that deduplicating only by `name` will remove both `{id: "asd", name: "Hi"}` and `{id: "123", name: "Hi"}` since they'd be considered duplicates of the last `{id: "123", name: "Hi"}` in the array when keying by `name`.

Replace `o.name` with whatever key you want to deduplicate by.